# Stokes' theorem for the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(y,-x,xz)$ on the surface $z=9-x^2-y^2$

Tags: integration, vector-fields, parametrization, stokes-theorem, iterated-integrals

> Verify Stokes' theorem for the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(y,-x,xz)$ on the surface $z=9-x^2-y^2$ with $z\geq 0$.

So I've tried finding the parametrisation which is $$\vec{r}(\theta,r)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,9-r^2), \qquad r\in [0,3], \ \theta\in [0,2\pi].$$Its normal vector is $$\vec{N}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \theta}\times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial r}=\dots=((9r-2r^2)\cos\theta,(9r-2r^2)\sin\theta,-r)$$ But then I checked a random normal vector on Geogebra and it just doesn't seem perpendicular. Is it actually wrong?

[image: Image of the surface and a randomly chosen normal vector]

I've been trying to look for mistakes but I can't find any. Is it actually like that?

And then for the rest of the problem, I found that $\nabla\times\vec{F}=(0,-r\sin\theta,-2)$, so
\begin{align}
\iint_S (\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F})\cdot\vec{dS} &=\iint_S (\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F})\cdot\vec{N}d\theta dr \\ &=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 (-(9-r^2)^2 r\sin\theta+2r)drd\theta \\ & =\dots \\ &=18\pi,
\end{align}
while the solutions says the answer is $-18\pi$. Have I done anything wrong? Is the normal vector incorrect too?

Comment: The normal vector should be $(2 r^2 \cos \theta , 2 r^2 \sin \theta , r ) $

Comment: @ghasheem that's so true. Do we have to check on the surface of $z=0$ on $x^2+y^2=9$? Or do we only have to check on all the surfaces when it is asking for the flux of a surface?

Comment: @TeM okay... But if it asked me the flux of that surface mentioned ($z=9-x^2-y^2$ for $z\geq 0$), I would indeed have to consider the $z=0$ with $x^2+y^2\leq 9$ surface, right?

Comment: Where did the exercise specify how the surface is to be oriented? I see no evidence. And why did you decide to use the order $\theta,r$ rather than $r,\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the vector field $\mathbf{F} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ of law:

$$
\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) := (y,-x,xz)
$$

and given the support of a surface:

$$
\Sigma := \left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : z=9-x^2-y^2,\,z \ge 0\right\}
$$

whose natural parameterization turns out to be:

$$
\mathbf{r}(u,v) = \left(u\cos v,u\sin v,9-u^2\right),
\quad \quad \text{with} \; (u,v) \in D := [0,3] \times [0,2\pi)
$$

by *definition*, the flux of $\nabla \land \mathbf{F}$ through $\Sigma$ is equal to:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi 
& := \iint\limits_{\Sigma} (\nabla \land \mathbf{F})\cdot\mathbf{n}\,\text{d}S \\
& = \iint\limits_D (\nabla \land \mathbf{F}) \cdot \left(\mathbf{r}_u(u,v) \land \mathbf{r}_v(u,v)\right)\text{d}u\,\text{d}v \\
& = \iint\limits_D \left(0,\,u^2-9,\,-2\right) \cdot \left(2u^2\cos v,2u^2\sin v,\,u\right)\text{d}u\,\text{d}v \\
& = \int_0^3 \text{d}u \int_0^{2\pi} \left(-2u-18u^2\sin v+2u^4\sin v\right)\text{d}v \\
& = \int_0^3 -4\pi\,u\,\text{d}u \\
& = \boxed{-18\pi}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Then, as required by the exercise, we verify by applying the *rotor theorem*:

$$
\Phi = \int\limits_{\partial\Sigma^+} \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{t}\,\text{d}s = \int_0^{2\pi} \left(3\sin v,-3\cos v,0\right)\cdot\left(-3\sin v,3\cos v,0\right)\text{d}v = \int_0^{2\pi} -9\,\text{d}v = \boxed{-18\pi}
$$

and with this the exercise can be considered concluded.

Answer (score 1):

Without any use of polar coordinates:

The position vector of the given surface $S$ is $\vec r=\langle x,y,9-x^2-y^2\rangle$, $D: x^2+y^2\leq 9,$ and its area element vector is $\vec{dS}=(\vec r_x\times\vec r_y)dxdy=\langle2x,2y,1\rangle dxdy$. We find the curl of the given vector field $\vec F=\langle y,-x,xz\rangle$ as $\vec\nabla\times\vec F=\langle 0,-z,-2\rangle$. Hence, the flux of the curl is equal to
$$\iint_S\vec\nabla\times\vec F\cdot\vec{dS}=\iint_D(-18y+2x^2y+2y^3-2)dxdy=\iint_D(-2)dxdy=(-2)(9\pi)=-18\pi$$
where the integral of the odd degree monomials is zero due to symmetry.

The position vector of the boundary contour $\partial S$, $x^2+y^2=9, z=0$ is $\vec r=\langle x,y,0\rangle$. Hence the contour integral can be computed as
$$\int_{\partial S}\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int_{\partial S}ydx-xdy=\iint_D((-x)_x-y_y)dxdy=\iint_D(-2)dxdy=-18\pi$$
by use of the Green's theorem. Note that $\iint_Ddxdy=Area(D)=9\pi.$